# How to search and replace text using linux script awk?

Tags: linux, scripting

I want a single CGI file that I can run on Cron that just does a simple search and replace on two small text files on my HostGator server, running Linux.

In one directory on my server, I have a text file named:

```
/public_html/stockmarketmagician.com/text_files/BarChartOpinions/001.txt
```

If that text file is opened in a text editor, the contents would read:

```
percent buy">100%</span> <span class="opinion-signal buy">Buy
```

But I want it to read as follows:

```
100% Buy
```

and saved back to the server, using the original name of '001.txt' in that same directory.

In another directory on my server, I have a text file named:

```
/public_html/stockmarketmagician.com/text_files/BarChartOpinions/ShortTerm/001.txt
```

If that text file is opened in a text editor, the contents would read:

```
buy"> 100% Buy
```

But I want it to read as follows:

```
100% Buy
```

and saved back to the server, using the original name of '001.txt', in that same directory.

NOTE: The gap between 100% and Buy should be one tab character.

UPDATE: I need to be able to run this from my browser. I have been able to create below script that I can run using my internet browser. I added the complete path to where the file is and where I want it written to. (see below). For some reason, it's not working.

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Content-Type: text/html
echo
echo "Running OVERALL..<br>"
# Run OVERALL
echo `awk -F '<' '{print $1}' test.txt| awk -F '>' '{print $2}'` " " `awk -F '>' '{print $4}'
/public_html/stockmarketmagician.com/text_files/BarChartOpinions/Overall/Overall-001.txt` >
/public_html/stockmarketmagician.com/text_files/BarChartOpinions/Overall/Overall-001.txt
echo "<br><b>Done with Overall-001!!</b>"
echo
echo
echo "Running OVERALL..<br>"
# Run SHORT TERM
echo awk -F '>' '{print $2}'` 
/public_html/stockmarketmagician.com/text_files/BarChartOpinions/ShortTerm/Shortterm-001.txt` > 
/public_html/stockmarketmagician.com/text_files/BarChartOpinions/ShortTerm/Shortterm-001.txt
echo "<br><b>Done with Shortterm-001!!</b>"
echo
echo
```

Comment: It's confusing with the quotes. Just paste the actual and desired file contents and put 4 spaces or 1 tab in front of each line in order to have it formatted by SO.

Comment: I have removed unnecessary quotes. Now only those quotes are mentioned which are included in text file.

Comment: waiting for anyone's help please!

Comment: It's a too unclear what you're asking. Do you want to keep everyting after `>` until (end of line or next `<`)?

Comment: I think i am quite clear about my requirements. I just want the text '100% Buy' from both files while ensuring a TAB character in between '100%' and 'Buy'.

Comment: any help or guidance?

Comment: waiting for some help please!